# Is there any software available in the market that can be used to automate PDF testing?

Tags: manual-testing, pdf-file

I have do PDF file checking but I am not satisfied about any tools any one help me please give me solution how to test PDF files in manual testing.

Comment: Please be more specific about what you need to check about the PDF file?  Layout?  Colors?  A table of values?  An image?  Size?

Comment: What do you need to test and how are your PDF files generated? Depending on the PDF structure the "best" answer could be anything from a comparison utility to the human eyeball.

Answer (score 2):

What are you testing for?

Tools:

- [Typo's](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-free-spell-style-and-grammar-checker-for-English) are easy, there are spell-checkers for that.
- [Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools) is fairly easy as well, a good compare tool will reveal all changes between versions.
- [PDF validation](http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx) has tooling as well.

In between:

- Basic info like the correct version CAN be done by scripting but likely is faster manually.

Manual:

- Layout.
- Correctness and completeness of the information. A real review in fact. Here my 'tool' [advice](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2586872/) would be training.

References:
https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-best-free-spell-style-and-grammar-checker-for-English
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools
http://smashinghub.com/10-best-file-and-documents-comparison-tools.htm
http://www.pdf-tools.com/pdf/validate-pdfa-online.aspx
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2586872/

Comment: please give me link this link is used but not satisfy.

Comment: which of the 5?